# Sending and Receiving Information from a Server using AJAX and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, database, server

I'm working on a webpage that is to interact with a database on a server using AJAX and JSON.

The page is supposed to send **two pieces** of information to a server (an id number and an event) and returns a table of the information for the person that matches the ID number (`fname, lname, sex,` etc). I have the form created and it validates correctly, however, I have no idea where to go from here.

I dabbled in AJAX in a past project but was unable to get it to work, and I have never used JSON (not even sure what it does). If anyone could help me out, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>Welcome to our People Finder Database</h2>
  Pleae fill out the following form to find information on the person you are looking for. <br>

  <form onsubmit="return validate()">
    ID:<input type="text" id="id"> <br>
    Event Type:
    <select id="event" name="cards">
        <option value="selectEvent">Please select an event</option>
        <option value="BIRT">Birth</option>
        <option value="DEAT">Death</option>
        <option value="BURI">Buried</option>
    </select> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            return checkEmpty();
        }

        function checkEmpty() {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("event");
            var ev = document.getElementById("id");
            var selectedEvent = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            if(selectedEvent == "selectEvent" || id.value == "") {
                alert("Please enter an ID number or Event Type");
            }
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What interface does your server support? What kind of back-end (server-side) technology you are going to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace 'targetUrl' with the action url of the form. (eg: 'target.php')

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 6</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        return checkEmpty();
    }

    function checkEmpty() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("event");
        var ev = document.getElementById("id");
        var selectedEvent = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedEvent == "selectEvent" || id.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter an ID number or Event Type");
        }
    }

    $('document').ready(function(){
       $('#submit_btn').on('click',function(){
         $.post('targetUrl',$('#myform').serialize()).success(function(response){
            //code to handle response from server
         });
      });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: black;
        color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px double blue;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Welcome to our People Finder Database</h2>
Pleae fill out the following form to find information on the person you are looking for. <br>
While neither field is required, you must fill out at least one of the two fields to receive any information <br>
Also note that the ID number should be the letter "I" followed by a number. <br>
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return validate()">
    ID:<input type="text" id="id" name="id"> <br>
    Event Type:
        <select id="event" name="cards">
            <option value="selectEvent">Please select an event</option>
            <option value="BIRT">Birth</option>
            <option value="DEAT">Death</option>
            <option value="BURI">Buried</option>
        </select> <br>
    <input type="button" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"> <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your new to storing and retrieving data, I would definately reccomend the services that https://parse.com/ offeres. It makes storing and retrieving data trivial. Best of all, the service is free unless your app makes more than 30 API requests per second. I have an app that 61 users use daily and we have never come close to the 30 req per second limit.

To save your info, you could write:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#submit_btn').on('click',function(){ // detect button click, need to add "submit_btn" as the id for your button

        var EventInfo = Parse.Object.extend("EventInfo"); //create a reference to your class
        var newObject = new EventInfo(); //create a new instance of your class

        newObject.set("id", $("#id").val()); //set some properties on the object
        newObject.set("event", $("#event").val()); //set some more properties on the object
        newObject.save(null, { //save the new object
          success: function(returnedObject) {
            console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + returnedObject.id); 
          },
          error: function(returnedObject, error) {
            console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }
        });
     });
});
```

Retrieving that info later would be as easy as:

```
    var EventInfo = Parse.Object.extend("EventInfo"); //create a reference to your class
    var query = new Parse.Query(EventInfo); //create a query to get stored objects with this class
    query.find({
      success: function(results) { //"results" is an array, you can fine tune your queries to retrieve specific save objects too
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];

          console.log("Result #"+ (i+1)); 
          console.log("Id = "+ object.get("id"));
          console.log("Event = "+ object.get("event"));
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("Failed to complete Query - Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
```

---

If you have to use a existing database to store the information you can send it to a php page like below, but note that with this method you still have to write the php page to actually store the data and retrieve it later, much more work and a lot more stuff to learn IMHO.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        $('#submit_btn').on('click',function(){ // detect button click, need to add "submit_btn" as the id for your button
           //get the inputted values 
            var dataString = 'id=' + $("#id").val()
                       + '&event=' + $("#event").val()
             //make the ajax call 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://mywebsite.com/mypage.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                  //do something with the returned data
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This looks great, will have to try it out tomorrow. On the last section of code for using a preexisting database, would the URL be the address to the database?

Comment: No, the url would be to the php page that you'd have to write to actually save the information to the database and then retrieve it. But if you wanted to go that route you'd have to at least learn some basic php (http://php.net/docs.php) and how to use PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to save and retrieve your data safely. Not to mention, you'd have to set up and maintain the database itself which can be a bit daunting or at least it was for me, after a lot of confusion there I found parse and it was just easy.

Comment: Well the thing is I'm not actually writing the database, it's already been created. My page is just supposed to display the information that matches the id entered by the user.

Comment: In that case, the ajax method will do half the job for you.That is, it will get the information to a php page that is capable of storing the information. You'll need decide which method you want to use to store the information and retrieve it. I'd recommend a php page that uses PDO to store and retrieve your information